# Testing multicollinearity assumption for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, multicollinearity, assumptions

My model is dealing with survey data for a mixed-effects logistic regression model. All of my variables in the model are categorical (most are binary). What can I use in R to assess the multicollinearity assumption?
Model:

```r
mixed_model_one <- svyglm(Sick ~ Wash_Binary + Food + 
       MotherEducation + Vaccination + Salary + Hamlet + 
       (1 | Household), data = df, family = binomial, 
       design = survey_design_mixed)
```

`Sick, Wash_Binary, Food, MotherEducation, Vaccination`, and `Salary` are binary. `Hamlet` has 5 unordered levels.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What assumption do you want to test?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to test the multicollinearity assumption

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "the multicollinearity assumption." Unless multicollinearity is complete among some variables, you can always build a model; you just might have very high individual coefficient standard errors for multicollinear predictors. Also, variance inflation and multicollinearity aren't quite so strictly associated in logistic regression as they are in linear regression. In linear regression you can estimate the variance inflation directly from the predictor values, but in logistic regression you need to evaluate the full model.

Comment: Decades ago Daryl Pregibon wrote the single best paper *Logistic Regression Diagnostics* However, most stat packages still don't offer these diagnostics for logistic regression that are readily available for multiple regression, e.g., VIFs, collinearity indexes, influential observations, etc. That said, a reasonable proxy or workaround is to run your LR model through a regression model package which offers these diagnostics. It's better than nothing. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-9/issue-4/Logistic-Regression-Diagnostics/10.1214/aos/1176345513.full